# Casting of types: byte vs int (Java)

Tags: java, integer, byte

```
    byte b = 1;
    b = -b; //i get highlited in red in here
    
    int a = 1;
    a = -a; //it is ok for jvm
```

why if (b = -b), then I get a mistake, but if i do the same with int, it is OK? What is the reason?

Sorry for such a newbie question, but I can't understand reason myself, neither found answer in google of SO.

Comment: All Java integer operations are promoted to `int`, then assignments get made.  So when you take `b` and multiply it by -1, it becomes an `int`.  Then you have to tell the compiler it's ok to assign the `int` to a byte by casting it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3